# визуализация базы данных wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, пытаюсь на вордперссе написать свой плагин. В котором будет одна база данных и пользователь из под админики сможет ее редактировать (удалять, добавлять, изменять). Создал базу данных, но не могу понять как ее визуализировать, для пользователя - нужно ли создавать input'ы для каждого поля и кнопки отдельно или все таки в wordpress есть для таких типовых задач уже встроенные механизмы? Мой код ниже:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: msv-Price item
Description: Create the list with hierarchies of services
Version: 1.0
*/

global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = '1.0';

function jal_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $jal_db_version;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    $table_name_price_cat = $wpdb->prefix . 'price_cat';    

    $price_cat_sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name_price_cat (
        id  int(120) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";   
    dbDelta( $price_cat_sql );


    $table_name_price_items = $wpdb->prefix . 'price_items';
    $price_items_sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name_price_items (
        id int(120) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        price double(10,2) NOT NULL,
        cat_id  int(11) NOT NULL,
        ordering int(11) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY  (cat_id) REFERENCES ".$table_name_price_cat."(id),
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $price_items_sql );
    add_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );
}

 function price_item_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Price item setup page', 'Price item', 8, 'service_itemes', 'price_item_init' );
}

function price_item_init(){

    global $wpdb;
    $items = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'price_items';
    $categories = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'price_cat';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $items.id, $items.name, $items.price, $categories.name as cat 
                                  FROM $items,$categories WHERE $items.cat_id = $categories.id 
                                  ORDER BY cat_id", ARRAY_A);
    $currentLine = "";
    $closetags = "";
    foreach ($result as $info){
        if ($currentLine != $info['cat']){
            $currentLine = $info['cat'];
            echo $closetags;
            $closetags = "</table>";
            echo "<h2><center>".$info['cat']."</center></h2><table>";
        }
        echo "<tr><th><a href=#>".$info['name']."</a></th><th>".$info['price']."</th></tr>";        
    }
    echo "</table>";
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install_data' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'price_item_setup_menu');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю надо копать в сторону этого класса https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_table
Он позволяет наладить обработку любых таблиц любых данных.